# Issue with arguments with quotes in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to run a simple python script which accept one argument and print it.
I am executing this python script using keyword **Run** present in **Operating System** library of **Robot Framework**.

I am trying to execute in following two ways:

```
${rc}   ${output}=  Run And Return Rc And Output    python "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\abc.py" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"
```

Output is coming proper in this case :

```
Documentation:  
Runs the given command in the system and returns the RC and output.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20151119 16:01:57.147 / 20151119 16:01:57.179 / 00:00:00.032
16:01:57.147    INFO    Running command 'python "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc.py" "C:Program Files (x86)Common Files" 2>&1'.  
16:01:57.179    INFO    ${rc} = 0   
16:01:57.179    INFO    ${output} = C:Program Files (x86)Common Files
```

However when I try to run in below way, it's giving error :

```
${rc}   ${output}=  Run And Return Rc And Output    "C:\\Python27\\python.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\abc.py" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"
```

Error:

```
16:12:44.481    INFO    Running command '"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc.py" "C:Program Files (x86)Common Files" 2>&1'.    
16:12:44.481    INFO    ${rc} = 1   
16:12:44.481    INFO    ${output} = The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

If I run same thing on command prompt, it works fine.

```
C:\Windows>"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc.py" "C:Program Files (x86)Common Files"
C:Program Files (x86)Common Files
```

Just want to know where I am going wrong for second case with Robot Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RobotFramework is not using a shell to run the command, but rather is passing it verbose to Windows. So it's looking for a filed named literally `"C:\Python27\python.exe"` instead of `C:\Python27\python.exe`. Note the wrapping quotes, usually those quotes are processed by the shell before invoking the command. So, you should change the command to `C:\\Python27\\python.exe "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\abc.py" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files"`

To better understand the difference of the shell argument you can try to compare the result of

```
subprocess.check_call('"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc.py" "C:Program Files (x86)Common Files"')
```

versus

```
subprocess.check_call('"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc.py" "C:Program Files (x86)Common Files"', shell=True)
```